# How to call subclass method (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, oop, subclass, superclass

I'm fairly new to Java. I was working on an assignment where I have a superclass and several subclasses, where some subclasses have attributes that the others don't. Essentially, I have to make an array of SuperClass objects, and then initialize each element of the array with one of the subclasses.

However, when I try to use one of the subclasses' specific methods, I get a compiling error telling me that the method **.getY()** wasn't found in the **SuperClass**, when it is clearly defined as a method from **SuperClass**.
I boiled down the problem to the following code (making sure I still get the same error):

```
public class StackOverFlow {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    /*
    SubClass obj = new SubClass(4, 5); 
    System.out.println(obj.getX()); 
    System.out.println(obj.getY()); 
    */
    SuperClass[] arr; 
    arr = new SuperClass[5]; 
    arr[0] = new SubClass(5, 10); 
    System.out.println(arr[0].getX());  
    System.out.println(arr[0].getY()); 
}}

public class SuperClass {
private int x; 
public SuperClass(int x){
    this.x = x; 
}
public int getX() {
    return x;
}
public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}}


public class SubClass extends SuperClass{
private int y; 
public SubClass(int x, int y){
    super(x); 
    this.y = y; 
}
public int getY() {
    return y;
}
public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
}}
```

When I use the code that's commented I don't get an error, which probably means the error comes from incorrectly using the array of classes.
Can anybody help me out?

Comment: `arr` holds instances of `SuperClass` and that class doesn't have a method `getY`

Comment: You cannot use sub class specific methods on the more generic super class. Look into casting and the use of instanceof if you want to work it around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your declared array `arr` is an array of type (class) *SuperClass* objects. Everything in the array must be a thing that is a *SuperClass*.

Your subclass named *SubClass* ***IS*** a thing of type *SuperClass* — it is an extension of that class, by adding `y` and `getY`, but it still conforms to *SuperClass*. Anything that you can do with SuperClass you can also do with SubClass, so you are allowed to add *SubClass* objects to the array of type *SuperClass*.

Where your error is, at `arr[0].getY()`, the thing that is in the spot at `arr[0]` is, in fact, a SubClass, because you just put it there, but *there is no guarantee* that that is the case — the only guarantee is that things in the array are of the type *SuperClass*, and things of type *SuperClass* don't have a `getY()` method.

When you *know* that a thing is of type *SubClass* you can [cast](https://www.baeldung.com/java-type-casting) it, like: `(SubClass) arr[0]`, and must parenthesize it to apply the cast *before* you attach the method call, so it would be `((SubClass) arr[0]).getY()`
Casting has it's own potential errors, if you try to cast something to *SubClass* when that thing isn't actually a *SubClass* it will cause an error (but that is another discussion).

So the answer to the question "How to call subclass method" is to *cast* the object to the subclass:

```java
// Direct replacement for your line of code:
System.out.println( ((SubClass) arr[0]).getY() );

// or assign it to another variable first:
SubClass sc = (SubClass) arr[0];
System.out.println( sc.getY() );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll have to learn more about casting. I was pretty lost before, but now I can see what to do. And yeah, I can see why those names would be confusing. On my actual assignment I named the classes a different way (Lavadora and Herramientas) but I thought it would be easier to generalize it. Now I see that it might just confuse someone who tries to help me. I'll keep that in mind for the future

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a method on `SubClass` but your array is of type `SuperClass[]`, you must **cast** the object:

```
SuperClass[] arr; 
arr = new SuperClass[5]; 
arr[0] = new SubClass(5, 10); 

SuperClass elem = arr[0];
SubClass subClassElem = (SubClass) elem; // here's the cast
subClassElem.getY();

// or shorter:
((SubClass) arr[0]).getY();
```

If you're unsure what's in the array use `instanceof`:

```
SuperClass elem = arr[0];
if(elem instanceof SubClass) {
  SubClass subClassElem = (SubClass) elem;
  subClassElem.getY();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about casting. I'll read about it, but this definitely helped to solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

The method getY() is not defined in SuperClass and as your arrays is of type SuperClass it it don't recognize it.
You can cast the array object to SubClass to specify the type :

```
        System.out.println(((SubClass) arr[0]).getY());
```